# What type of moth is this?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, lepidoptera

[image] What type of moth is this that was on my wall in Spain

Comment: please provide the approximate size of your moth. Also, indicating a bit more info about your location (urban, suburban, rural, etc.) and time (of day; of year) can be helpful in getting an accurate ID

Answer (score 1):

It looks very much like *Manulea palliatella*, Family Erebidae, Subfamily Arctiinae. 
https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Eilema_palliatella
These are present in Spain.